# Typescript property to be placed in css for angular 2

Tags: html, css, mongodb, angular, typescript

I want to take a typescript value that i will store in mongoDB but is currently in an array, which i haven't done yet, in the app component but i want to place it as the background colour property in my css file or maybe even use style.

This is app.component.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/home">{{title}}</a>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/mypalettes">My palette</a></li> 
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" >
        <div class="input-group">
          <input #inputHex (keyup.enter)="submit(inputHex.value)" type="text" class="form-control" 
          size = "110" placeholder="Enter the hexcode of the colour">
          <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" (click) = "submit(inputHex.value)">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="/signup"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
          <li><a href="/login"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <!-- routing here -->
     <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is home.component.html

```
<br>
<br>

<!--<a href="#" >Edit popular page</a>-->
<div >
  <br>
      <span (mouseover)='hover()' class="card" *ngFor = "let hexa of 
         colourHex" >
        <br>
        {{hexa.id}} 
      </span> 
</div>
```

This is home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  title = '#000000'
  colourHex =  [ {
      "id": "#ff0000",

  },
{
      "id": "#dd0000",

 },
{
      "id": "#bb0000",

} ]; 


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  hover(){
    console.log("test");
  }

}
```

Comment: try using [ngStyle]